# KeyFactory.generatePublic() takes lot of time/hangs for long time

Tags: java, rsa, freeze

I am using the following key factory instance:

```
factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA", "BCFIPS");
```

When I am generating public key in below code, it hangs for long time:

```
publickey = factory.generatePublic(spec);
```

Sometimes the code returns in 1 minute, sometimes in 5 minutes and sometimes 10 minutes.

Any idea if there is any known issue.
This problem is happening only on RHEL 6. In RHEL7, it works fast.

Comment: Does it respond differently if you just use `KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue with slow entropy generation.  See  [Avoiding JVM Delays Caused by Random Number Generation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13209_01/wlcp/wlss30/configwlss/jvmrand.html).

The gist is that you must use `/dev/urandom` instead of `/dev/random`.
Open the `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security` file in a text editor
and change the value of `securerandom.source` from `file:/dev/random` to 
`file:/dev/urandom`.

However, be aware that the quality of the random numbers generated will
be inferior and if you're worried about state-level attacks you should
just accept the delay and continue to use `/dev/random`.

Note that at one time there was an issue where the system would use `/dev/random`  even if you specified `/dev/urandom`. If you change this and *still* see long delays, change it to `/dev/./urandom` to avoid the hardcoded test.

Comment: No, but key generation does.

Comment: He's not doing any key generation, the `generatePublic()` actually just takes existing key material and basically deserializes it into a Java class. Even still, your explanation is the most likely cause of the problem. It may be that one of the classes somewhere initializes an instance of SecureRandom whether it's used or not.

Comment: I don't know why someone voted down your answer. I fear my comment emboldened someone, I don't know. I have upvoted.

Comment: Thank you for all comments. I remember solving similar issue a year back with urandom. Not sure if it is same one. I will try and update.